# Скрипт Автозаполнения - выдаёт отладочные сообщения (в некоторых браузерах)

Tags: html, jquery, form

Доброго всем дня.
Есть скрипт автозаполнения поля формы (скрипт на jQuery)
Форма:

```
<form>
...
<input id='tags' name='fio' type='text'...>
...
</form>
```

Раньше работал нормально.
Но если переносить проект на флэшку (FAT32) и обратно (NTFS), то скрипт начинает выдавать:

```
[x] result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.
```

Проверил целостность и идентичность скриптов, в них всё до байта одинаково.
Проверил файлы (Tot.Commander) по содержанию с работающим проектом - файлы идентичны.
Что может так повлиять на скрипт?
Проявляется в Хроме и Опере.
Почему именно перенос на Flash так на него влияет?

Comment: Что за скрипт, нам прделагается узнать самим?

Comment: Есть только одна мысль: изменилось время модификации файла и это  сказалось на отдаваемых заголовках и, как результат, на кеше  браузера. ETag + If-None-Match и Last-Modified + If-Modified-Since

Comment: Скрипт такой: 
http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @artoodetoo Пока не сильно понятно, но что-то в этом есть. И какой из этого выход? Пробовал на 5-ти разных ПК. Там кэш точно ни чего не кэшил. Так как ресурс открывал на них впервые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был в этом!
Это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Заменил на это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

И всё заработало!
P.S. Бред какой-то. Неделю промучился.

Answer (score 1):

Из англоязычного стековерфлоу https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091534

```
$("#find-subj").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
});
```

Comment: Можно сказать, что практически помогло...      

Но css всё равно почему-то слетает.

http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Дебагер показывает потерю связи с CSS почему такой может происходить?